# Another reduction to halting problem solution

Tags: logic

> Given an arbitrary program Q, does Q halt for the input 0?

Call the decider for `Q` `decider`. Therefore we define `decider(Q)` that always halts, returns true if  `Q` halts on `0` and false otherwise.

By definition, we know the program `Halts? (P, I)` that decides if program `P` halts on input `I` cannot exist. Thus for reduction, define it as

```
def Halts? (P, I):
  if(decider(P)) return true;
  else return false;
```

But now we have solved the halting problem, contradiction

Is this correct?

Comment: So your program `Halts? (P, I)` rejects the input `I` and answers if `P` halts on input `0`. Why would that be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program takes `P` and `I` but then ignores `I` and runs `decider(P)`, effectively answering the question: does `P` halt on `0`? That's not what it should be doing.

As a hint for the correct solution:

> Let `Halt? (P, I)` build a program `Q` that accepts a number as an input and then runs `P(I)`. (Don't run `Q`, just build it!) Then output `decider(Q)`.

Comment: Ok and if decider(Q) returns true means P, I halted and if it returns false P, I did not halt, hence solvign the halting problem, contradiction?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

(I assume by 'o' you mean an empty input string)

No, this doesn't work. The decider(P) routine only checks whether the program P halts when given the empty Input string or not, and not whether it halts for the given input I in general.

Indeed, notice that your halts(P,I) routine gets I on the input, but then does *nothing* with it. So your halts(P,I) routine is not a routine that would solve the halting problem on the basis of the existence of the decider(P) routine.